# Why cannot run compiled JavaFX 11 class?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-11

Following instructions at https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#install-javafx, I compiled the sample HelloFX.java via:

```
 javac --module-path $PATH_TO_FX --add-modules=javafx.controls /Users/me/Documents/java/HelloFX.java
```

But now if I attempt to run that...

```
 java --module-path $PATH_TO_FX --add-modules=javafx.controls /Users/me/Documents/java/HelloFX
```

... I get error:

```
 Error: Could not find or load main class .Users.me.Documents.java.HelloFX
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: /Users/me/Documents/java/HelloFX
```

Yet the file reported as not found is there:

```
 ls -l /Users/me/Documents/java/HelloFX.class
 -rwxr--r--  1 me  staff  1336 Oct 30 16:01 /Users/murray/Documents/java/HelloFX.class
```

(I had already changed permissions to add `u+x` in case that was the issue, but apparently that was not the trouble.

What's wrong?

(Yes, `$PATH_TO_FX` does point to `javafx-sdk-11/lib`.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question was already answered in the [openjfx-dev](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/openjfx-dev/2018-October/022783.html) mailing list:

> The "java" command expects a fully-qualified class name, not a file path as
>   its argument

For completion:

- The [javac](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/javac.html) command deals with filenames, which means you can compile a java file from any location:

  ```
  javac [ options ] [ sourcefiles ]
  ```
- However the [java](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/java.html) command deals with classes:

  ```
  java [options] mainclass [args...]
  ```

  where `mainclass` specifies the name of the class to be launched, not the filename or location.

Providing you have Java 11 installed (and `JAVA_HOME` is set at it), the JavaFX 11 SDK downloaded, and just following the getting started [guide](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#install-javafx):

- Download the [HelloFX](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/HelloFX.java) class to any location, i.e `/Users/<user>/Downloads`.
- Open a terminal and cd to that location:

  ```
  cd /Users/<user>/Downloads
  ```
- Set the JavaFX path:

  ```
  export PATH_TO_FX=/path/to/javafx-sdk-11/lib
  ```
- Compile the class:

  ```
  javac --module-path $PATH_TO_FX --add-modules=javafx.controls HelloFX.java
  ```

  Check that `HelloFX.class` is created at the same folder level.
- Run the class:

  ```
  java --module-path $PATH_TO_FX --add-modules=javafx.controls HelloFX
  ```

  It should run just fine.

Now, if you try to run the above command from a different location it won't work, because the `HelloFX` class is not available in the classpath.

So if you want to run this class from a different location you'll need to specify this classpath:

```
javac --module-path $PATH_TO_FX --add-modules=javafx.controls \
    /Users/<user>/Downloads/HelloFX.java

java --module-path $PATH_TO_FX --add-modules=javafx.controls \
   --class-path /Users/<user>/Downloads HelloFX
```